# Combine two javascript onclick events

Tags: javascript

I have an input button that calls a window.location.href event, and also want to add google analytics event tracking to the same button...

How would I combine these two events into one statement?

```
<input type="button" value="Learn More!"  onclick="window.location.href='site1'" />
```

and this event:

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/externalsite/site1']);"
```

Comment: It is ok in this instance, but be wary of adding too much inline code to an HTML element; things can get messy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use jQuery.

But a quick fix is to just combine them:

```
<input type="button" value="Learn More!" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/externalsite/site1']); window.location.href='site1'" />
```

Statements are separated with a semi-colon.

Answer (score 3):

Concatenate both, and add them together:

```
<input type="button" value="Learn More!"
       onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/externalsite/site1']);
                window.location.href='site1';" />
<!-- Within HTML tags, newlines don't matter. For readability, I have split the 
      attributes over three lines-->
```

Note that the order **matters**. If you first use the `window.location.href` assignment, the second part can be ignored, because the page unloads.

Comment: @aCodeSmith I appreciate good edits, but you should not edit answers just to add a non-critical whitespace character. Spaces after semicolons are a matter of preference, so I recommend to not send in such edits in the future.

Comment: I think I clicked on the wrong answer. I wanted to add that space to my code, not yours. Oops.  :P

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
function handleClick(){
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/externalsite/site1']);
  window.location.href='site1'
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Learn More!"  onclick="handleClick()" />
```

Comment: This way is a lot more manageable. Better then having the onclick contain two different items. Even better would be to use a juery event.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="button" value="Learn More!"  onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/externalsite/site1']); window.location.href='site1'" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try moving your JavaScript off the element like so:

**HTML**

`<input type="button" value="Learn More!" id="myBtn" />`

**JavaScript**

```
(function(d, w) {
    var btn = d.getElementById('myBtn');
    btn.onclick = function() {
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/externalsite/site1']);
        w.location.href = 'site1';
    };
}(document, window));
```

It is always a better idea to use Unobtrusive JavaScript when you can. You can read more here:

- http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-technique/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can combine statements with a semicolon:

```
<input type="button" value="Learn More!"  onclick="window.location.href='site1'" />
```

In your case, make sure to call the redirect as the last operation, it could be that execution is terminated when you are leaving the page.